# data retrievement is so slow in mongoDB

Tags: database, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

im using mongoDB alongside spring boot
i'm wonder is there any way to retrieve data from DBref collection in an objective way?
for example in my person class there is @DBref private UserAccountType userAccountType and in userAccount we have an enum calls Role. If in a method i get a role and want to find all persons with Role.Driver, i should first find all userAccountType that their role is driver and then find all persons who has that userAccountType id.
something like this

```
Query query = new Query();
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("staticRole").in(StaticRole.DRIVER_BRONZE, StaticRole.DRIVER_SILVER));
            query.fields().include("id");

            List<UserAccountType> userAccountTypeList = mongoOperations.find(query, UserAccountType.class);

query = new Query();
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.orOperator(
                    Criteria.where("phone").is(phone),
                    Criteria.where("phone2").is(phone)
            );
query.addCriteria(criteria);
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("userAccount.userAccountType").in(userAccountTypeList));

Person person = mongoOperations.findOne(query, Person.class);
```

and all this lookups make my app very slow. We know our database design is so bad. but we have no time. is there any way to do this operations simply?

Comment: I dont see any other way where you can improve significantly. Do you have indexes on the database matching this query?

Comment: @pvpkiran thank you for answering. yes i have index on phones and roles

Comment: How big is the `userAccountTypeList` ? May be you need just distinct values?

Comment: Mongo indexes work only when you are querying in the same order in which it is created. Based on your query, the index should be like `phone_phone2_userAccountType`